# How long does a JBoss application try to auto connect to DB when the DB was shut down?

Tags: jboss, database-connection, jboss7.x

We use JBoss 7.1 version in our environment. We have a scenario where one of the production databases was shut down for one hour due to a maintenance activity. Our JBoss application failed to automatically reconnect to that database after one hour and we had to manually restart the application to establish the connection.

Below are the database validation parameters we have defined in our code. Please let me know if I missed any parameter for automatic reconnection other than the below or if we have to make/add any changes/parameters to the existing.

```
<validation>
     <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1;</check-valid-connection-sql>
     <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
     <background-validation>true</background-validation>
     <background-validation-millis>180000</background-validation-millis>
</validation>
```

`<background-validation-millis>` ---> This parameter allows a connection checker to run for every three minutes as per our code and finds the availability of the DB connection.

Questions:

- How long does this run for database connection?
- Or, what is the maximum time/loops it will try for database connection?
- Is there any default time it runs or will it run infinite times until the database comes back up?

I hope my questions are clear and please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s13.html) and I read that `<validate-on-match>` is typically not used in conjunction with `<background-validation>`.

Try remove this tag and see what that gives.

Comment: Thank you. But we had specified <validate-on-match> parameter as "False". Will that still make an effect on background validation?

Comment: @SaiKiran You have specified it, but why did you specify it? From the documentation: *"Prior to JBoss 4.0.5, connection validation occurred when the JCA layer attempted to match a managed connection. With the addition of <background-validation> this is no longer required. Specifying <validate-on-match> forces the old behavior. NOTE: this is typically NOT used in conjunction with <background-validation> "*

Comment: @SaiKiran You are running on JBoss 7.1, did you specify the tag to force old behaviour (ie the behaviour before JBoss 4.0.5)?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried removing the parameter <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match> from the validation parameters completely but still my Jboss application is not able to auto connect to DB after the DB reboot. We still have to manually restart the application to establish the connection to Datasource. Could you please suggest further on this !!

Comment: @SaiKiran Hi Sai. I have nothing that I can think of at the moment. What I'd suggest is ask the question anew and have a lot more details about your setup. I.e. the specific database you are using, the full configuration of the data source and a detailed description on how to reproduce, the exact JBoss version. The reason to ask again would be to get front-page views again. If you do ask again, it would be best to delete this question so as not to "double-post". GL.